# Java CSVWriter adding blank line at the end of file

Tags: java

CSVWriter's last parameter is the lineEnd - since I want a new line after every row, I have been putting "\r\n" and it's been working well for me.

However, I realize that it is adding a blank line at the end of the file I'm assuming because of this. Is there a way I can get it to not add that blank line without having to read the file again?

Here is my code:

```
        try (PreparedStatement ps = extractTest.Connection.prepareStatement(extractTest.querySQL); ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")  
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(out, separator, quoteChar, escapeChar, "\r\n");
            writer.setResultService(rsHelper);
            writer.writeAll(rs, extractTest.headerRow);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
```

This code adds a blank line at the end of the file - any ideas?

Comment: Why are you adding blank lines? [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2) says each line is a record, so technically speaking you're inserting empty records, which could trip some reader that cannot handle these empty lines.

Comment: The way that it's working right now, it's only one empty line at the end of the document. I think this is because of the lineEnd parameter. If I replace the line end parameter with "", it doesn't put each row on a new line.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your question. So, yes, you need CRLF as line separator (per RFC). The RFC also allows to have a line break at the end of the file. Is that what you are seeing? That should be ok. Or does your output end in two CRLFs?